# Coordinate charts vs. coordinates on manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, coordinate-systems

I just realised that I'm confused what coordinates really means in the context of manifolds.

For example, say $M=S^2$. Then we can define smooth charts as follows: Let the open sets be $U = S^2$ minus the north pole and $V=S^2$ minus the south pole and then $\varphi : U \to \mathbb R^2$ the [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) $(X,Y)\mapsto ({x\over 1-z}, {y \over 1-z})$.

I have no trouble visualising these maps. But there are several things that bother me.

For example, $S^2$ is two dimensional. This is supported but the fact that there are two component coordinates $(X,Y)$. But: in order to define these one assumes a point on $S^2$ is given by $(x,y,z)$. Cartesian coordinates in $\mathbb R^3$. I used to think that if a manifold has $n$-dimensions a point on it is given as an $n$-tuple $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ which is used to define a map into $\mathbb R^n$.

> Please could someone tell me what I misunderstand about coordinate
>   charts?

The second thing that I am confused about is this:

> When people write something like local coordinates $x_1, \dots, x_n$ for
>   the manifold $M$ does one really mean charts $\varphi_1, \dots,
>  \varphi_n$?

The coordinate charts define what each point $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is so I assume one cannot speak meaningfully of coordinates of a manifold unless one is talking about charts. Or am I missing something?

When I am writing about coordinates I use $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ to denote a bunch of numbers, like $(1,2,3,4)$, basically the coordinates of a vector as in linear algebra and coordinate charts are the maps that transport a similar bunch of numbers in $\mathbb R^4$ to $(1,2,3,4)$.

I want to define a contact structure on a manifold. Some easy examples in  order to better understand. But:

The [standard contact structure](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Contact_manifold) on $S^3$ is given by the contact form $xdy - y dx$.

> If we'd have the stereographic projection charts for $3$-dimensions,
>   as above, would this contact form now be $XdY - Y dX$ or really just
>   $xdy - y dx$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say you have no problems visualising the stereographic projections you (probably) see the sphere as embedded in $\Bbb R^3$.

To define a chart you have to tell which point in $U$ goes where. You can't do this unless you give the points names a priori to having access to a chart. In the special case where the manifold in question lives inside some $\Bbb R^N$ ($N > n$) it might be convenient to use their Cartesian coordinates in $\Bbb R^N$ as such names. Once you defined a chart you can use its inverse to refer to the manifold points. Now you are left with an "$n$-dimensional namespace": an $n$-tuple is enough to reference a point. If a point $p \in \Bbb R^n$ references a manifold point $q$ via a chart, then there is a neighbourhood of $p$ in $\Bbb R^n$ which is diffeomorhic to a neighbourhood of $q$ in $M$. By contrast, in each neighbourhood of $q$ in $\Bbb R^N$, there are point, which are not used as names for manifold points. That's why $N$ doesn't say anything about the dimension of your manifold, whilst $n$ is actually used to define the dimension of $M$.

"When people write something like local coordinates $x_1,…,x_n$ for the manifold M", they usually refer to a single chart $x: U \to U' \subset \Bbb R^n$ and use $x_1, \dots x_n$ as abbreviatons to the projections of $x$ to it's component in $\Bbb R^n$, precisely: $x_i := pr_i \circ x$, where $pr_i: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is the projection to the $i$th component relative to the standard coordinates of $\Bbb R^n$. So it is actually the chart combined with what you do, when you use coordinates in linear algebra.

Unfortunatly I can't help you with the part of your question concerning the contact structure. But as I understand the link you gave, you missed some termes in the definition of the standard contact strucure? Because $S^3$ lives in $\Bbb R^4$, so you can name it's points after their cartesean coordinates $(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)$ and then the contact structure would in these cartesean coordinates be given as $\alpha_0 = x_1 d y_1 - y_1 d x_1 + x_2 d y_2 - y_2 d x_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a few questions regarding the second paragraph. Concretely: When you say to use the inverse of the chart to reference a point -- does this mean I use $(X,Y)$ to mean a point on $S^2$? Or $({2X \over X^2 + Y^2 + 1}, {2Y \over X^2 + Y^2 + 1}, {X^2 + Y^2 - 1 \over X^2 + Y^2 + 1})$?

Comment: I think I will be able to work out the last part of my question once I can figure out what the inverse of the stereographic projection is.

Comment: Do all manifolds live in $\mathbb R^N$ for some $N$?

Comment: Concerning your first comment: Yes, for the sphere with stereographic projections the inverse has exactle the form you wrote down. In a general setting: If $x: M \supset U \to U' \subset \Bbb R^n$ is a chart, then a point $\eta \in U' \subset \Bbb R^n$ adresses a point in $M$, namly $x^{-1} (\eta)$. And as every point of the manifold is contained in some coordinate chart, you can use the charts to adress the manifold point. But take care: different charts may need different point in $\Bbb R^n$ to adress the same manifold point (e.g. stereographic projection wrt to north /south pole).

Comment: Concerning your last comment: The answer is actually yes. There are famous results (the embedding theorems of Whitney and Nash, see wikipedia), which yield that every $n$ dimensional manifold is embedded in some $\Bbb R^N$. Both theorems are not at all trivial and there are easy examples (Moebius strip and Klein bottle are famous ones)  where $N > n+1$. But: Actually I concider the possibility to work with manifolds independent of their embeddings as the biggest advantage of modern differential geometry. I hope you'll understand as you get more ivolved in the field... Good questions btw...

Comment: Thank you! You helped me greatly. But now I am wondering: In the case of $S^3$ if a point $(X,Y,Z)$ in $\mathbb R^3$ maps to a point $({2X\over X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 + 1}, {2Y\over X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 + 1}, {2Z\over X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 + 1}, {X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 - 1\over X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 + 1})$ then wouldn't the contact structure be $$ \alpha_0 = {2X\over X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 + 1} d {2Z\over X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 + 1} - \dots$$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with this. I never worked with contact structures, so all I could do is reinterpreting wikipedia for you, but I don't think this would be a good idea. Maybe you could make a new question out of this, linking to this one?

Comment: Yes, I will do that. Thank you a lot for your help!